# How to add a header before the output in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, geneos, itrs

Within ITRS I am trying to print "Current Java Directory" before I print the output of the file in Windows.

On the Windows command line, I am using:  `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c type D:\Apps\Statements\Alerts\java_path_validation.txt` .

**Currently right now within ITRS it is displaying this below**:
[image: value_from_text_file]

**What I am looking to do:**

But I need to have "Current Java Directory" as the header right now where C:\Program Files (x86)Java\jre7.  And then beneath it, I need to have C:\Program Files (x86)Java\jre7 as the value.

Is this something I can do from the command line using an echo before, I execute:  `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c type D:\Apps\Statements\Alerts\java_path_validation.txt` .

Comment: Is ITRS displaying the Window Title?

Comment: Thanks Squashman.  I hope I'm understanding you correctly.  But ITRS is just reading what I am sending via the command line including the .txt file.  So the Window title is populated with the value in the .txt file.

Comment: Typing a text file will not make the console window title change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the resolution.  You have to echo the heading first followed by an ampersand "&" with the type command within ITRS so it can run it on the command line:

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c echo Current Java Directory & type D:\Apps\Statements\Alerts\java_path_validation.txt`